# why do i keep getting the same $SHELL even i am on a different shell already

Tags: linux, centos, shell-script

```
[oracle@SJOAM ~]$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
[oracle@SJOAM ~]$ sh
sh-4.1$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
sh-4.1$ csh
[oracle@SJOAM ~]$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Why am i always in bash !? but the prompt are already different when i am in sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### why do I keep getting the same $SHELL

> The SHELL environment variable does not indicate what shell you are
>   currently using. It is simply set, when you log in, to the value of
>   the login shell field of `/etc/passwd`, which in your case is
>   `/bin/bash`.
>
> If you want to change your login shell, run `chsh` (**ch**ange
>   **sh**ell).
>
> The login shell set in `/etc/passwd` controls, among other things,
>   what shell is run when you open a terminal emulator, such as
>   gnome-terminal.
>
> To see what shell you are currently using, try `ps -p $$`

Source http://www.ubuntu.com answer [csh - which $SHELL still gives /bin/bash](https://askubuntu.com/a/111170/376050) by [geirha](https://askubuntu.com/users/9016/geirha)